# Why did my sudoers file suddenly reset itself?

Tags: ssh, debian, sudo

After setting up Wave in a Box on my Debian server, I started noticing strange things happening: I could no longer use sftp to transfer files, and even worse, I couldn't run any sudo commands! Thankfully, I could still `su` to root. When I checked `/etc/sudoers`, I found that it had been completely reset, with only the root user having sudoer permission.

I don't think my server was hacked, since I'm running denyhosts to shut out any attempts. Any idea what could have caused `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to reset themselves?

Answer (score 2):

The Debian system cares so as not to mess up with your configs, but who knows? Did you recently upgrade your sudo (`cat /var/log/apt/history.log`)? Which version do you have installed? If you are running Debian Sid, you might have been adversely affected by an update to [**1.7.4p4-6**](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sudo/news/20110111T193211Z.html). The upload was meant to fix [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609641).

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the packages were purged and reinstalled. Purging removes old config files and reinstall would bring you back to the default state.